# How to have a Python glue job return when called in step function?

Tags: python, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have a glue job, in python, that I call from a step function. The step function successfully starts the job. The job successfully finishes. But the step function never moves to the next step. Is there some required configuration/permission for the step function to respond to job success? Something to do in the python script?

Here is the step function (state machine) definition:

```
"MyGlueTask": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "JobName": "my_glue_job"
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.MyGlueTask",
  "Next": "NextGlueJob"
}
```

Comment: How did you invoke the Glue job? Can you share your step function definition (called `State machine definition` in aws console)?

Comment: Added the state machine for job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution to my actual problem was permissions. You need four permissions when running a `startJogRun.sync`:

- glue:StartJobRun
- glue:GetJobRun
- glue:GetJobRuns
- glue:BatchStopJobRun

Those are actually the Terraform values, but should help anybody struggling with this.

Comment: Thanks for this, saved my day! Just wondering why we need the last one `glue:BatchStopJobRun`?

Comment: and a quick one: can you get the resource link for this glue job in the Statemachine execution event history?

Comment: Thanks.  This was the case for me.  I first created a state machine only containing `startJobRun` with an auto-created role.  This role does not contain some permissions required by `startJobRun.sync` because they are not needed.  When I edited the definition of the state machine with `startJobRun.sync`, but no change to the role, this resulted in the same situation as this question.  I could fix this by recreating the state machine with `startJobRun.sync`, then the auto-created roles contain the required ones.  One may also directly edit the existing role.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it never moves to the next step? Maybe it does, but, for instance, in 5 minutes?

I'm asking that because Step Functions has the limitation: even if your Glue job executes in a few seconds, Step Functions polls the results from Glue job once every 5 minutes actually.

A kind of workaround you could implement is to change `arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync` to `arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun` — then Glue job task just will trigger the Glue job and will move to the next step.

Most likely, you will need to wait the Glue job finished and get some result out of there. Therefore, you need to wrap the previous state with a few more ones.

1. The main purpose is to merely start the Glue job. Apart from that, we need Glue job `RunJobId`. 
   I don't know if it can be retrieved from Glue job itself, so I've created a Lambda to run the Glue job using boto3 `start_job_run` function and then get `RunJobId` from the response.
2. Create a Lambda which will be grabbing the status (`JobRunState`) of the Glue job (via boto3 `get_job_run` function) by `RunJobId` from the previous step.
3. Using `Wait` Step Functions state type, run the Lambda you created every N seconds.
4. Use `Choice` state type to filter Glue job statuses out.

   - If `RUNNING`, go back to the `Wait` step.
   - If `SUCCEEDEED`, then go ahead to the next state.
   - If `[FAILED | STOPPED]`, go wherever else.

Finally, it looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06oG3.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for the information. My problem ended up being much simpler, related to permissions.